# Can't Access Function from another Class in Cocos2D

Tags: ios, xcode, cocos2d-iphone

I've implemented 3 classes.

-`Scene.m & .h`

Scene.m: (has HudLayer & BackgroundLayer properties on the header file)

```
    -(id)init{

        self = [super init];
       if(self != nil){
    //Level1Layer

            _level1GameplayLayer = [Level1Layer node];
            [self addChild:_level1GameplayLayer z:0];

    //Hud Layer

           _hudLayer = [HUDLayer node];
            [self addChild:_hudLayer z:1];

       }
      return self;
   }
```

-Which holds these 2 layers

`BackgroundLayer.m & .h` && `HUDLayer.m & .h`

Everytime I click the screen I get a Log notice like this "Touched Screen"(called on backgroundlayer.m) which is followed by a function which is implemented on `HUDLayer.m & .h`

I call it like this:

```
    [_hud getAmmo:self.ammoLeft magsLeft:self.magsLeft];
```

`_hud` is stated on the `Scene.m` like this:(and its imported on `backgroundlayer.m`)

```
    HUDLayer *hudLayer = [HUDLayer node];
    [self addChild:hudLayer z:1];
```

background is z:0.

Also BackgroundLayer.m has the property under @interface: 
**(I realized this is nil because its not initialized, How do I initialize this???)**

```
    @property (strong) HUDLayer *hud;
```

Between the call of getAmmo: I make 3 CLOGS, one BEFORE "We're about to getAmmo:"

one INSIDE the function on HUDLayer.m that calls "Inside getAmmo:"

and one AFTER "We gotTheAmmo:"

BackgroundLayer.m:

```
    CCLOG(@"We're about to getAmmo");
    _hud getAmmo:self.ammoLeft magsLeft:self.magsLeft];
    CCLOG(@"We got the ammo:%d, mags:%d",self.ammoLeft,self.magsLeft);
```

HUDLayer.m:

```
    -(void)getAmmo:(int)ammo magsLeft:(int)magsLeft
     {
        CCLOG(@"We did this");
       hudMagsLeft=magsLeft;
       hudAmmoLeft = ammo;
       CCLOG(@"HUD MAGS: %d, AMMO:%d", hudMagsLeft,hudAmmoLeft);
     }
```

Im only getting the one before and the one after, there's no warnings on the way the function is being called but for some reason it isn't being called. There's no if statements or anything..what is it Im doing wrong???

So to make the question more simple, how do I access properties/functions from other classes?

Thank you for your time, have a good one.

Comment: I think you're going to have to post some more code…  It isn't at all clear to me where your `_hud` variable is supposed to be assigned (is `_hud` nil?).  And without any context around the call to `getAmmo:magsLeft:` it's hard to tell what else might cause the call to not be made.

Comment: I've assigned  @property (strong) HUDLayer *hud; at the top file(Im sorry I was making that edit just now..)

Comment: As Aaron said, we need more information. At least, we need all code where `_hud` is assigned/changed, the lines around the call og `get Ammo` (at least from log before to log after), and maybe the code of `getAmmo. Better is the smallest overall code, that reproduces the error.

Comment: Are you assigning the created hudLayer to _hud? ie, `HUDLayer *hudLayer = [HUDLayer node]; _hud = hudLayer;`

Comment: @SmugbitStudios if I do that on the init block of BackgroundLayer.m I get an infinite loop...

Comment: I see what you're doing, now. You need to pass in the HUD created in the Scene to the BackgroundLayer init, and assign that to _hud. Currently, when you are calling _hud in BackgroundLayer.m, it is undefined.

Comment: @SmugbitStudios How do I pass the HUD created in the scene to the backgroundLayer?? I guess that would be the question hahaha
Btw, thanks for your time!

Comment: Check the "Creating the HUD" section of this: http://www.raywenderlich.com/4666/how-to-create-a-hud-layer-with-cocos2d

Comment: @SmugbitStudios I had followed that but then I added the Scene files, and everything went smut.

Comment: NeverMind, I got it. Thanks for bearing with me man.

Answer (score 0):

On the scene.h I added this function:

```
    -(id)initWithHUD:(HUDLayer *)hud;
```

Then on the scene.m I made this:

```
    _backgroundLayer = [[[BackgroundLayer alloc] initWithHUD:_hudLayer] autorelease];
```

on Backgroundlayer.m I changed regular init with

```
    -(id)initWithHUD:(HUDLayer *)hud{
```

:D